# Best practice to communicate JSF and JS

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I know how to [pass variables from JSF to Javascript](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html#PassVariablesFromServerSideToClientSide), and I normally embed them like this in my xhtml:

```
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                setData('#myid', '#{dataController.items}');
            });
        </script>
```

What I don't fully like is that I encode in Java the specific format required by the JS library, so it doesn't look very elegant/scalable. For example, I obtain `Map<String, Integer>` from my database, and then I encode in Java the data that JS requires like f.ex.:

```
for...
   String s += "["+ ... +"," + ... + "]";
```

This is when I need to pass something like `[val1,val2], [val3, val4]...`, that I later paste in a JSON all at once in the correct format:

```
'data': {
            'values': [formattedVarFromJSF],
```

But sometimes I need to use very different layouts, like:

```
'data': 
                {"values":[var1FromJSF]},
                {"values":[var2FromJSF]},
...
```

And I code in JSF the whole `{"values":[ + var(i) + ]}` which I dislike, because changing the library will mean I need to change my Java code.

I could also use a Java Map object in the same format as the JSON and just print it, but this seems a bit coupled.

The best way I could find is to isolate JSF from mapping JS and just use it to retrieve data, by printing a map like this in the xhtml:

```
    <script>
       var kvArray = [
       <c:forEach items="#{dataController.map}" var="m">
          {key: #{m.key}, value: #{m.value}}, 
       </c...>
       ];
    </script>
```

And then leave the JS to deal with it, mapping it according to the specifics of the library or function.

Is there a more efficient and elegant way to solve this issue? What are the best practices for this?

Comment: _"I could also use a Java Map object in the same format as the JSON and just print it, but this seems a bit coupled."_? Why? Sound like a better way than your 'last' solution (the 'better way')

Comment: @Kukeltje well, I will need one Java Map for each format I need. So the input format needed by the JS library is bound to my Java code. Now the JS library decides to change "values" to "vals" and I will have to change my Java code. The 'better way' I found isolates this problem, so it is up to my JS code (which knows how to use the library) to render the data... You can see the benefits

Comment: @BalusC yes, but this conversion (either automatic with gson for example or manual) implies I need to know the JS library input format from Java, so I am questioning if this is a good idea.

Comment: I would provide the data as JSON from the server side and define a simple adapter in JavaScript for each different format you need.